# Django Multi-App Database Router not working

Tags: python, django

I'm doing a project using Django 1.10 and Python 2.7.

I have read and tried to implement database routing according to [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers). I have also read up on a lot of different tutorials and other stackoverflow questions. However, I can't seem to get it to work.

This is the scenario that I have:

I need all analytics, auth and admin apps models on the default database. Then cancellation app on a separate database, and driveractivity app on another separate database.

This is the router that I'm using:

```
from django.conf import settings


class AppRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'analytics':
            return 'default'

        elif model._meta.app_label == 'cancellation':
            return 'cancellations_db'

        elif model._meta.app_label == 'driveractivity':
            return 'driveractivity_db'

        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'analytics':
            return 'default'

        elif model._meta.app_label == 'cancellation':
            return 'cancellations_db'

        elif model._meta.app_label == 'driveractivity':
            return 'driveractivity_db'

        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model=None, **hints):    
        if app_label == 'cancellation' and db == 'cancellations_db':
            return True

        if app_label == 'driveractivity' and db == 'driveractivity_db':
            return True

        if app_label in ('analytics', 'auth', 'admin', 'contenttypes', 'sessions', 'rest_framework') and db == 'default':
            return True

        return False
```

My database settings are as follows (**settings.py**):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'NAME': 'analytics',
        'USER': 'root'
    },
    'driveractivity_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'NAME': 'driveractivity',
        'USER': 'root',
    },
    'cancellations_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'NAME': 'teke_cancellation',
        'USER': 'root'
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['analytics.AppRouter.AppRouter']

DB_Mapping = {
    "cancellation": "cancellations_db",
    "driveractivity": "driveractivity_db"
}
```

**models.py - cancellation**

```
class Cancellation(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.EmailField(max_length=255,blank=False)
    time = models.DateField(blank=False)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'cancellation'


class PenaltyType(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'cancellation'


class Penalty(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.EmailField(max_length=255,blank=False)
    meted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    penalty_type = models.ForeignKey(PenaltyType)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'cancellation'
```

**models.py - driveractivity**

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(null=False)
    driver_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=False)
    vehicle_reg = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    lng = models.FloatField()
    lat = models.FloatField()
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'driveractivity'


class DistanceDetails(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(null=False)
    driver_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=False)
    vehicle_reg = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=False)
    new_lng = models.FloatField()
    new_lat = models.FloatField()
    last_state = models.CharField(max_length=15,null=False)
    last_lng = models.FloatField()
    last_lat = models.FloatField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'driveractivity'
```

Edited **router.py**

```
class AppRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return DB_Mapping.get(model._meta.app_label, 'default')

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return DB_Mapping.get(model._meta.app_label, 'default')

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model=None, **hints):
        if app_label in DB_Mapping.keys() or db in DB_Mapping.values():
            return True
        else:
            return None
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

check if this works for you:

**settings.py**

```
DB_Mapping = {
    "cancellation": "cancellation_db",
    "driveractivity": "driveractivity_db",
    ...
}
```

**router.py**

```
from project.settings import DB_Mapping

class MyRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return DB_Mapping.get(model._meta.app_label, 'default')

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return DB_Mapping.get(model._meta.app_label, 'default')
```

i do use a similar setup where i route to a different database user based on the group of the user who's making the request.

the allow_migrate can also be written similarly., where if the `db == 'default'` or `if model._meta.app_label in DB_Mapping.keys() or db in DB_Mapping.values(): return True else False`

Comment: This still creates the models in the default db. Still can't tell why

Comment: Can you make sure you have app-label in your models. That is the only way this can go wrong with the above code., I'm essentially saying return the default database if no mapping is found, else return the mapped database.

Comment: I have added the app_label via the Meta class on the models, but it still does not work. The tables are still created in the default database.

Comment: is it possible to paste some snippets of your settings.py, router.py and models.py
u need to tell django to use your custom router instead of the default one by setting the:
    DATABASE_ROUTERS = (
        'project.customRouter.myRouter',
    )

Comment: I have edited the question to include the requested details

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['analytics.AppRouter.AppRouter']
```

might need to be instead:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['analytics.router.AppRouter']
```